# Call recording app

Tags: applications, voice-recording

I would like to get an app, that can record also incoming and outgoing calls and it should record mine and also my partner's voice.

Comment: Please, write also what version of Android is installed on your device

Comment: Android version: 4.4.2

Comment: What about my reply? You can try that app, then, if it works, you can mark the question as solved. Thanks

Comment: No, sorry, but not the same...

Comment: Please link the question with same answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Top-rated automatic call recorders in Play Store are -

- [Automatic Call Recorder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appstar.callrecorder&hl=en) - by Appliqato
- [Call Recorder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nll.acr&hl=en) - by ACR

They serve your purposes and are supported on Kitkat versions also.

Answer (score 0):

I find many simply with search in google play: 
[call recorder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appstar.callrecorder&hl=it) should be exactly what you ask

Comment: Yes, I see, but some of these do not record each party's voice.

Comment: Have you also tried the linked app? It work with your android version and has a lot of good comments